# Database modeling to migrate to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I and my colleagues will migrate from firestore to MongoDB and we need to find a suitable way or a tool to analyze the firebase schema and know exactly the model for each collection and each sub-collection inside a collection in a nested level.

I tried to write a script but it was tedious due to the level of sub-collection we have.
I was able to get collection and sub-collections but I found it is hard to loop on each document and get its schema.

So any suggestions?

Comment: You may have a look at this [Migrate Firestore Mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@parcelaexpress/migrate-firestore-mongo)

Comment: > migrate-firestore-mongo is a database migration tool for MongoDB running in Node.js